# Is it possible to get recent 5 emails using the gmail -API from one specific sender

Tags: gmail-api

Through another question I was able to limit the number of results but I was wondering if there is a way to filter the  messages and only pull them from one sender?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query parameter (q) which supports [advanced search syntax](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering). For example, if the sender you want messages from is: `mysender@mydomain.com`, [you can use](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list):

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxresults=5&q=from:mysender@mydomain.com`

Take into account that this will only send back the id and threadId of the emails. If you want more info about the messages you should use [messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) for each message.